# Itertools stop characters repeating in a row

Tags: python, python-itertools

I wrote the following code to make all strings of 20 characters long with combinations of A, T, G and C.

However, I would like to avoid more than 3 of the same characters in a row, so I added an if function to check for this. The trouble is, this is after the itertools code, so it's a bit slow. I wonder whether there is a way to use itertools to produce this result without having to run itertools and then an if function?

```
import sys
import itertools
import re

x = ["A","T","G","C"]
for i in itertools.product(x, repeat=20):
        i = "".join(i)
        if re.search(r"(\w)\1\1",i):
                continue
        else:
                sys.stdout.write(i)
```

Comment: `permutations` doesn't have `repeat` keyword argument. Are you sure this is your code? also what do you mean by *avoid more than 3 of the same characters in a row*?

Comment: I am pretty sure it's intended to be `product`, which *does* take a `repeat` argument and which unlike `permutations` does what *jonc* wants it to do.

Comment: have you tried numpy choice to take random samples of your list:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice

This way you can specify exactly how many you want.

Comment: jonc, the number of 20-character strings taken from ATGC with no identical triplets is bigger than the number with no identical duplets, which is 4 (for the first character) times 3**19 (for the remaining characters) or about 4.6 billion. (The actual number is quite a lot bigger, but I'm too lazy to calculate it exactly.) It's going to take a looong time to write them all to stdout. What are you actually intending to do?

Comment: Even if you had a really fast way to check each string, you're iterating over 4^20 > 1 trillion strings. This will take a long time.

Comment: sorry - changed to permutations to product, which it was intended be. It seems this might take longer than expected. I don't need all those 1 trillion strings, just a large number, providing one of them doesn't match to the genome I will subsequently search them against, then that is fine. The problem is when I run at the moment, the first ones, as you might expect, are all  AAAAAAAAA etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At face value, the question appears to be asking this:

> How can I filter this enormous list of strings without the pain of having to construct the whole list first?

The answer to that is: you're already doing it! The things in `itertools` produce lazily-generated sequences that are constructed iteratively. So your existing code is *not* producing an enormous list of billions of strings.

But there's a possibly more interesting question you might be wanting to ask:

> If I generate the triplet-free strings by generating all the strings and filtering out the ones with triplets in, my code is having to do extra work because most of the strings generated will have triplets in them. Suppose the strings are generated in lexicographic order; then the first 4**17 of them will begin AAA, and we really ought to be able to skip over all of those. How can we do better?

Unfortunately, if you want to do *this* then you will have to write your own code to do it; `itertools` doesn't offer this sort of "pattern-filtered product" functionality.

It might look something like this:

```
# generate all n-tuples with the property that their k-th element
# is one of the things returned by successors(initial (k-1)-tuple).
# So e.g. the first element is one of the things returned by
# successors(()).
def restricted_tuples(successors, n):
    assert(n>=0)
    if n==0:
        for t in successors(()): yield (t,)
    else:
        for start in restricted_tuples(successors, n-1):
            for t in successors(start): yield start+(t,)

def successors_no_triples(start, alphabet):
    if len(start)<2 or start[-1] != start[-2]:
        for t in alphabet: yield t
    else:
        banned = start[-1]
        for t in alphabet:
            if t != banned: yield t

print([''.join(x) for x in restricted_tuples(lambda start: successors_no_triples(start,'ABC'), 5)])
```

The `print` at the end is illustrative only. If you wanted to print out all the billions of strings from the original questioner's case, you'd do better to iterate over the sequence generated by `restricted_tuples` and stringify-and-print each one separately.

Incidentally, the number of length-20 sequences on 4 letters with this property turns out to be 415,289,569,968. You'll be waiting a while if you try to generate them all, especially if you actually want to *do* anything with each one.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I'll edit that to use a better name.

Comment: ... Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks. I slightly modified this so it prints on the fly, now I should get some usable strings (and hopefully one or more of them do not match to the genome I will search them against (which comprises long strings of characters A, T, G, C).